# Placing Scripts Into An Array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've just started programming in Unity and am not so good at it yet.
I'm trying to make a simple cookie clicker game and was watching [this 
tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrv7ubLSaws) and at around 18:34 he wrote down some code as seen below. I think his code is outdated and Unity does not work like it used to (I'm not sure though).

His Code

```
public Text Gps;
public Click click;
public ItemManager[] items;
public int getGoldPerSecond()
{
    int tick=0;
    foreach(ItemManager item in items)
    {
        tick +=item.count * item.tickvalue;
    }
}
```

My code:

```
public Text LPS;
public MainButton mb; //same as his Click click script
public ClicksPerSecondManager[] cps;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    cps = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("CPS");
}

public int getLikesPerSecond()
{
    int tick = 0;
    foreach(ClicksPerSecondManager item in cps)
    {
        tick += cps.count * cps.LikesPersecond;
    }
    return tick;
}
```

I know that the code cant access the variables or something. 
Would someone please explain to me how to store the objects into the array.

Whats happening here is that I have a shop and it has 3 items. This is the script attached to the 3 items

```
public Text itemDesc;
MainButton mainButton;
public float cost;
public int LikesPerSecond;
public int count;
public string itemName;
private float baseCost;
public GameObject sucessfulPurchase;
public GameObject failedPurchase;
public Image Panel;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    baseCost = cost;
  mainButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<MainButton>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    itemDesc.text =itemName+ "\nCost : "+cost+"\nLPS : "+LikesPerSecond   ;
}

public void purchasedItem()
{
    if (mainButton.noOfLikes >= this.cost)
    {
        mainButton.noOfLikes -= cost; //minus away cost
        count += 1;  
        cost = Mathf.Round(baseCost * Mathf.Pow(1.15f, count));
        sucessfulPurchase.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine(WaitFor1Second());
    }
    else if (mainButton.noOfLikes < cost)
    {
        failedPurchase.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine(WaitFor1Second());
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitFor1Second()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    if (failedPurchase.activeSelf == true)
    {
        failedPurchase.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (sucessfulPurchase.activeSelf == true)
    {
        sucessfulPurchase.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

So what I'm trying to do now is access the variables of `count` and `likesPerSecond` in these 3 objects and times them all together by using a foreach loop.

The problem that I'm facing is that I can not access these variables from my new script which basically tries to store all of these item scripts into an array (at least that's what I think the video is trying to do) and then multiply the variables together and get the sum.

The errors it gives me are:

> Cannot implicitly convert UnityEngine.GameObject[] to ClicksPerSecondManager[]

and

> ClickerPerSecondManager[] does not contain a definition for 'count' and 'LikesPersecond' (probably cause it cant access the script on the object)

I have faced a similar problem with this before in another project however it was a single object so I used

```
public Playerhealth hp;
hp = gameObject.FindObjectWithTag("Player").getComponent<PlayerHealth>();
```

However this time its supposed to be stored in an array and I have no clue how to write that.

Comment: You never told us the specific error that was happening.

Comment: What objects are you trying to store?  Your code doesn't indicate that at all.

Comment: I have edited the post. Really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that `cps = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("CPS");`
returns an array of `GameObject` so when you use a `ForEach`, each object which is returned, will be from Type `GameObject` so you ca not just use `foreach(ClicksPerSecondManager item in cps)` because `cps` doesnt contains an array of of `ClicksPerSecondManager`,it conatins an array of `GameObject` so you can do it like this

```
foreach(GameObject item in cps){
    ClicksPerSecondManager cpsm = item.getComponent<ClicksPerSecondManager>(); 
    //now you have access to its public properties or methods
    Debug.log(cpsm.count);
    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, your problem essentially lies here:

[image: The Problem]

You are correctly iterating over an array, but the two highlighted parts you reference the *array* again, not the single item in the array! Notice that `item` goes completely unused in your loop, there.

Milad Qasemi is also correct in that `FindGameObjectsWithTag` returns an array of `GameObects`, so his solution will definitely work. I just wanted to point out the logic error present, as you had a correctly formatted `foreach` declaration, just that the action being performed inside it was malformed.